# How to make wordpress page site.com/content as location for main site.com that is worked on nuxt.js+node?

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy

There are 2 containers with sites:
on nuxt.js
on wordpress
They work in the same environment, that is, they are visible to each other.
It is necessary in the 3rd container with Nginx to display the wordpress page as location / content when passing from nuxt.js.
That is, site.com works under node + nuxt, and when you go to the site.com/content link, we go to the wordpress page with posts. You also need the site.com/wp-admin link to work as a regular wordpress route and open a full-fledged wordpress admin panel. But wordpress itself can work on any other subdomain example.site.com, if there are difficulties with the wp-admin output. How to implement this using nginx + wordpress or suggest other options?

Comment: See the working example of nginx configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64670202/nginx-install-wordpress-under-some-uri-prefix-on-existing-website).

Comment: hm... maybe you didn't read my question
They are in different docker containers and not in one system.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is (easily) possible. Especially the requirements that specific folders should go to specific containers. Anyways, this question is not really fit for this Q&A, I think at ServerFault or another site you'll get better answers. Maybe it is even simpler to just fetch the WP pages from your JS application and display them, WP living on a custom subdomain

Comment: @kero I think it will be better to add functionality like blog on nuxt app, but not to wasting time to resolve this task... But it will be the next step. :D